# Using IMPORTHTML against Parkrun data and returning N/A

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the following call in google sheets

=IMPORTHTML("http://www.parkrun.org.uk/harrogate/results/eventhistory","table",1)

this used to pull in the table beautifully but has recently stopped working.

Anyone know why?

Cheers

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing:

A change in their robots.txt file, which presently mentions:

> robots.txt for parkrun event websites http://www.parkrun.org.uk http://www.parkrun.dk  etc   parkrun results are Copyright (c) parkrun.   Results are made available for personal, non-commercial use only.  We request that automated scraping does not take place.  If you have a legitimate requirement, please contact techsupport@parkrun.com so we can discuss  your  requirements.  See also http://www.parkrun.org.uk/scraper.html

and `Disallow:` includes:

```
 /*eventhistory$
 /*eventhistory/$
 /*eventhistory.aspx$
```

However, Excel has no issue with robots.txt in this case.